# How to extract a columns content in Microsoft Access Database using python

Tags: python, database, ms-access

I am just starting to learn python and was wondering if someone could help me pull column data using python?  I have been researching for about 3 hours.

code:

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jgp22\Documents\Database11.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from information')


for row in cursor.fetchall():
                  print(row)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jgp22\Desktop\Python\Data.py", line 3, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jgp22\Documents\Database11.accdb;')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) 
(SQLDriverConnect)')
```

error #2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jgp22\Desktop\Python\GrabData.py", line 3, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=MAD')
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 
Cannot open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database that your 
application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. (-1028) 
(SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot 
open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database that your application 
recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. (-1028)")
```

Comment: Does the row print out when you run it?

Comment: no it throws an error which i have just posted in the question.

Comment: Windows separates out 32-bit ODBC driver and 64-bit ODBC drivers. The bitness of your python and driver needs to match. You can see which python you are using just by typing python in CMD terminal. Go to ODBC Data Source Administrator to see if it is 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: I'm running a 64 bit machine

Comment: and python is 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create a Named System DSN

1. Go to ODBC Admin (make sure its the 64-bit one)
2. Click on System DSN
3. Create named DSN that points to 'C:\Users\jgp22\Documents\Database11.accdb' in this example lets use *myDsn*
4. Use the connection string `DSN=myDsn` where *myDsn* is the name you gave in step 3. Don't worry about the driver info or path. All of that is stored with the DSN record on the system.

### ODBC Data Source Administrator Paths

To setup DSN for **32-bit application** you must use:

`%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

and for **64-bit application** you must use:

`%WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe`

From https://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/windows-x64-32bit-odbc-vs-64bit-odbc/amp/

## Install the 64-bit Access DB Driver

The driver for accessing accdb files might not be available on your system. In that case, you are going to need to install the driver from Microsft. The accdb driver is available for download from Microsoft here:
https://microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

## Use 32-bit Python (if Access DB driver isn't available in 64-bit)

Another alternative if you have the 32-bit accdb ODBC driver already installed on your system is to use the 32-bit version of Python. An example of this type of environment might be if you had a 32-bit version of Office installed already.
Install the 32-bit version of Windows Python 3.7.0 from:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0.exe
When using the 32-bit version of python, you should access the DSNs under the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator.

## Connect to the Named DSN

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=myDsn')
```

Comment: Added section on paths to both ODBC tools

Comment: I believe I know that but the 64 bit only has sql server and 32 bit has Microsoft access driver and a bunch of other drivers and stuff

Comment: sorry took forever to download for some reason.  How would I include the DSN=mydsn(or MAD as I called it) in the python script, like what would that look like?   Thank you for being very helpful.

Comment: and every thing else just stays the same?

Comment: yeah, but we will know for sure in a few minutes when you run it. ;-)

Comment: Its saying that my database is corrupted?

Comment: Can you open the database with the Access GUI?

Comment: Which driver did you pick when you created the System DSN in the ODBC Admin GUI?

Comment: micrsoft access driver

Comment: I think I remember the ability to test the connection from the ODBC Data Source admin tool. If there is a test button, does it pass?

Comment: I dont see it.  could it be because the drive is an .mdb extension and my access database is a .accdb extension?

Comment: You'll need to install the accdb driver from here <https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255>

Comment: You can install the 64bit driver and use 64bit python or install the 32bit driver and use 32bit python. Microsoft advises against installing both drivers on the same machine.

Comment: Thank you so much you are the first person who has actually fixed one of my problems.  SO THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!